# Protected component checkbox in workflow task

Tags: workflow, tasks

While creating a new task for workflow there is a checkbox called Protected Component.from Help It says **Check Protected Component to mark the task as protected**.What does it mean by.Can someone explain me in detail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Protected components are a feature of managed packages, and are only available in Developer Edition where a Managed Package exists. Protected elements are restricted from being linked to or referenced in installing organizations, thus isolating them from the organization.

You may choose to protect an element only if it has never been released unprotected (e.g. you have never uploaded it in a major release with the protected flag turned off). You may choose to unprotect an element at any time, but if you upload a major release, it will no longer be eligible for protection. As long as it is protected, you may delete the component at any time.

This is relevant in a major way. If you want to include elements that you want to delete later, you may wish to have them be protected in order to prevent them being referenced. Once they are released once without protection, you may never delete the element (never say never, though, as it is technically possible, just much more involved).

If an unprotected component is deleted, it may cause future upgrades to an organization to fail if that organization references or links to the component and the upgrade would delete the component as a result. In that scenario, it then becomes necessary to undo the reference or link before you can upgrade to a package that includes the deleted component.

Elements can be "referenced" by, for example, including them in unmanaged Visualforce pages (e.g. Custom Labels), or in home page components (e.g. Custom Weblinks).

The following components can be protected:

> - Custom labels
> - Custom links (for Home page only)
> - Workflow alerts
> - Workflow field updates
> - Workflow outbound messages
> - Workflow tasks

-- [Protected Components](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=packaging_protected_components.htm), Winter 2014 Help

For less information, see [Protected Components](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=packaging_protected_components.htm).